# Item in listview showing package name

Tags: android, listview

I want to show data from my json to my `listview`. Here is what i try

```
   private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
        List<Itemadapter> items = new ArrayList<Itemadapter>();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        String[] ba = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String code     = obj.getString("ItemCode");
            String name     = obj.getString("ItemName");
            String photo    = obj.getString("PhotoName");
            items.add(new Itemadapter(code, name,photo));
            Log.i(code, code);

        }
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), items.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        ArrayAdapter<Itemadapter> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Itemadapter>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,items);
        listView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
    }
```

My `Itemadapter`

```
public class Itemadapter {

    String ItemCode;
    String ItemName;
    String ItemPhoto;

    public Itemadapter(String ItemCode, String ItemName, String ItemPhoto) {
        this.ItemCode   = ItemCode;
        this.ItemPhoto  = ItemPhoto;
        this.ItemName   = ItemName;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return ItemCode.toString();
    }

    public String getItemPhoto() {
        return ItemPhoto.toString();
    }

    public  String getItemName(){
        return ItemName.toString();
    }

}
```

when i run it, there is no error . But, in my `listview` i see something like this in multiplerows

> com.example.boby.firstapp.Itemadapter@(somecode)

How can i fix it ? did i miss something ?

Comment: what you want to show in listview? itemCode, itemName or itemPhoto?

Comment: what you want to show in listview? itemCode, itemName or itemPhoto?

Comment: @IshaanKumar yeah, something like that

Comment: something not gonna help. specify, so i can help. U decide.

Comment: @IshaanKumar sorry, what i want is show them in different columns . But it's fine if its only one column, i can use google later. sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `toString()` in `Itemadapter`:

```
public class Itemadapter {

    String ItemCode;
    String ItemName;
    String ItemPhoto;

    public Itemadapter(String ItemCode, String ItemName, String ItemPhoto) {
        this.ItemCode   = ItemCode;
        this.ItemPhoto  = ItemPhoto;
        this.ItemName   = ItemName;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return ItemCode.toString();
    }

    public String getItemPhoto() {
        return ItemPhoto.toString();
    }

    public  String getItemName(){
        return ItemName.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ItemCode + " " + ItemName;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayAdapter<Itemadapter> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Itemadapter>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,items);
```

This error comes because of this line. Let me explain. If you want to show itemCode in listview, then the code must be like this.

```
ArrayList<String> itemsCode = new ArrayList<>();   
for(int i=0;i<items.size();++i){
    itemsCode.add(item.get(i).getCode());
}
ArrayAdapter<> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,itemsCode);
```

The third parameter should be what you want to display

Answer (score 0):

The error is on the getters methods at `ItemAdapter` class, remove `.toString()` from all getters.

```
public class Itemadapter {

    String ItemCode;
    String ItemName;
    String ItemPhoto;

    public Itemadapter(String ItemCode, String ItemName, String ItemPhoto) {
        this.ItemCode   = ItemCode;
        this.ItemPhoto  = ItemPhoto;
        this.ItemName   = ItemName;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return ItemCode;
    }

    public String getItemPhoto() {
        return ItemPhoto;
    }

    public  String getItemName(){
        return ItemName;
    }

}
```

I hope it will help you!